# Ruby - parsing CSV with regex content

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing, csv

Have the following csv file (data.csv) which is used to store some reg expressions

```
row0 key1, key2, key3
row1 /[\S\s]+/, /[\S\s]+/ , /[\S\s]+/
```

Trying to parse this file using the csv library

```
csv = CSV.read("data.csv", headers: true)
```

The issue is that the strings are altered with while being parsed by csv.
for eg.

```
csv["key1"].first #=> "/[\\S\\s]+/"
csv["key2"][0] #=> "/[\\S\\s]+/"
```

Wondering why do we see those additional escape '\' character injected into the strings that hold a reg exp and is there a way to avoid this from happening?

As a side note, observed the same behavior while parsing tab delimited file with same content.

Comment: Show some of the data.csv file.

Comment: You are seeing that output in irb? To get a backslash literal in a double-quoted string as irb prints, it needs to be a double backslash.

Comment: In other words, your data is probably fine, but the double backslashes only appear when it is converted to a double-quoted string for console output. If you strip off the outer `/ /` delimiters, your regex should load  with `Regexp.new csv["key1"]`

Comment: For example: `Regexp.new csv["key1"].gsub(/^\/|\/$/, '')` creates the Regexp object `/[\S\S]+/`

Comment: Thank you Michael, yes I was looking at the console output. The suggestion to remove the outer ` // ` delimiters works for me. Will change this in the input csv file itself.